# Can a Typescript Click Event be handled by Generic inherited method

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following Generic method inside of base class that I want to reuse for dialogs since they share a lot of functionality:

```
  public onOpenCodeBasicDialog<U, V>(UCtor: new (...args: any[]) => U,
    dataSource: string, config: any, formControl: string, data?: any): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(UCtor, {
      width: config.width,
      height: config.height,
      data: data ? data : this.form.controls[formControl].value
    });

    this._dialogSubscription = dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((results: Array<V>) => {

      if (results) {
        this[dataSource] = new MatTableDataSource<V>(results);
        this.form.patchValue({ [formControl]: results });
        this.form.get([formControl]).markAsDirty();
      }
    },
      err => { this._done(err); });
   }
```

This works fairly well if I wrap a method "onOpenDialog" in my component class that extends the base class, which decides which dialog to open. So in my component class this method would look like the following:

```
public onOpenDialog(type) {
    if (type === 'entry_point') {
      this.onOpenCodeBasicDialog<SecurityReviewDetailCodeEntryPointsDialogComponent, EntryPointSchema>(
        SecurityReviewDetailCodeEntryPointsDialogComponent, '_entryPointsDataSource',
        { 'width': '60%', 'height': '60%'}, 'entry_points');
    } else if (type === 'entity') {
      this.onOpenCodeBasicDialog<SecurityReviewDetailCodeEntitiesDialogComponent, EntitySchema>(
        SecurityReviewDetailCodeEntitiesDialogComponent, '_entitiesDataSource',
        { 'width': '80%', 'height': '80%'}, 'entities');
    }
....
}
```

Then in my HTML, I can setup various click events to be handled by the onOpenDialog by passing in a type such as so

```
<button mat-button
                matTooltip="Edit" (click)="onOpenDialog('entity')">
<button mat-button
                matTooltip="Edit" (click)="onOpenDialog('entry_point')">
```

However, instead of using a wrapper for this, is there a way for the base class method to handle this directly instead of using the wrapper. Such as the following:

```
<button mat-button
                matTooltip="Edit" (click)="onOpenCodeBasicDialog<SecurityReviewDetailCodeEntryPointsDialogComponent, EntryPointSchema>(
                  SecurityReviewDetailCodeEntryPointsDialogComponent, '_entryPointsDataSource',
                  { 'width': '60%', 'height': '60%'}, 'entry_points')">
```

I have tried this but it does not like the syntax and creates malformed HTML. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: pretty sure that this is not gonna work, because the Component-classes cannot be resolved in the template

Comment: @tommueller - I think you are correct regarding types in the template